# Get Data from database using array values with for loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Array:

```
$ecodesAr = Array ( 
[0] => 1Z0-060 
[1] => 98-375 
[2] => 98-368 
[3] => 98-367 )

for($k=0; $k<count($ecodesAr); $k++){ 
$arrayTB[$k] = $this->Functions->exam('title', $ecodesAr[$k]); }
```

Modal code:

```
public function exam($q, $d) {
    $q = $this->db->where($q, $d)
                    ->get('exams');
    return $q->row();
}
```

Result:

```
Array ( 
[0] => 
[1] => 
[2] => 
[3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1091 [hot_exam] => 0 [top_exam] => 0 [category] => 114 [subcats] => 288 [slug] => 98-367 [sku] => OI5Ao [title] => 98-367 [name] => MTA Security Fundamentals [update] => 2021-09-16 [regular_price] => 130 [sale_price] => 59 [on_homepage] => 0 [on_request] => 0 [expired] => 0 [path_slug] => 98-367.pdf [questions] => 123 [demo_slug] => 98-367-demo.pdf [prc_price] => 65 [prc_demo] => 98-367-demo [prc_exam] => 98-367 [is_active] => 1 ) 
)
```

The First 3 values are skiped in the output and just the last value got, I want to all array data against values please help anyone!

Comment: Are you sure your query has a result for the first three entries of the array? Also, any reason why you're not just using forEach?

Comment: You do return a single row from your `exam()` method. If you want you could either return `$q` and traverse the result set from the caller or return the entire result set as an array from `exam()`.

Comment: in foreach has return same values its not foul of foreach and

Comment: Did you re-check your database has those titles? And btw, you can write the query like this: `$this->db->where('title', $array_values); `. More details in this [link](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

Comment: I write the same exact query init. and that's function has been working on other functions;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$productsarry = Array ( 
    [0] => Milk 
    [1] => Cream 
    [2] => Sugar 
    [3] => Yougert
);
for($k = 0; $k < count($productsarry); $k++) { 
    $arrayTB[$k] = query("select slug, qty, name, price from exams where title ='$ecode'")->row(); 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).